# How to create a file from System.IO.Stream in metro apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net

```
Stream stream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync( url );
```

How can i create a file in app's local folder having data downloaded through this stream as file content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do some kind of stream to stream copy. However, I happen to just use the response object in my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Stream stream = null;
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
    StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("savename.htm",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227171?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Something like this:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("yourfile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

[More information at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/18b44ccd-f5fa-4c24-ae58-5bc498d8d60c/)

Comment: I have to store data downloaded via the **stream** as the content of the file. How can i do that?